# connecting to LAN is a problem after wlan module attempted upgrade

Tags: networking, lan

short prestory: i've decided to updrade my internal wlan card. turns out not all lenovo models are open to all cards and on boot, if the change is attempted, it's normal to get something like "unauthorized network card is detected". system is halted until you reboot, put in the original card, and boot again. however:

the original card gives me kukish:
not only the airplane mode seems to be permamently enabled, the card itself is not listed anymore in the output of lspci. Only ethernet controller is detected, but the above message on boot disappears. I am assuming it means that the card is not visible, but somehow detected.

so. i boot again, plug in the cable and:

user@user-t410:~$ ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
ping: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): Temporary failure in name resolution
user@user-t410:~$ ifconfig
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
ether 5c:ff:35:0e:a3:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 1  bytes 64 (64.0 B)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
RX packets 816  bytes 65888 (64.3 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 816  bytes 65888 (64.3 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

user@user-t410:~$ sudo ifconfig enp0s25 up
[sudo] password for user:
user@user-t410:~$ ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
ping: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): Temporary failure in name resolution

and the same blasted airplane mode.

windows 7 connects through the cable ok, booting into a live distro is good too.

what am i missing? thank you all in advance.

Comment: From your question "Temporary failure in name resolution" This is a DNS error try ping an actual IP. You need to investigate why the DNS is not working.

Comment: user@user-t410:~$ ping 130.63.236.137
connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: OK so it appears not DNS. Now tat is out of the way you can move on to more troubleshooting. What version of Ubuntu are you using and what kernel?